# in sculpt mode the circle disappears when brushing

Tags: interface, sculpting, customization

the circle i'm talking about is this blue circle

[image]

whenever i starts brushing with any brush in sculpt mode the circle disappears
but i need it to be revealed. is there any way to keep it revealed

i'm using blender 2.82a

Comment: Yeah, this is an annoying change that makes it a lot harder to be precise. I don't think there's any way to change it yet: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/sculpt_paint/brush/cursor.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As of July 2020, there does not seem to be an option in Blender to display the sculpting circle cursor during a stroke.**

This seems like a huge oversight and workflow regression in my opinion. Sculpting with pressure-dependent radius feels like I'm trying to paint using an invisible brush.

**However, there is a code contribution on `developer.blender.org` that adds this functionality back in:**

[⚙ D6324 Sculpt: Sculpt plane cursor preview (`https://developer.blender.org/D6324`)](https://developer.blender.org/D6324)

It appears to be in need of work. They want some code changes, as well as explanations of why it's a positive change.

If you'd like to see this feature added, and you know how to code or just have time to spare, maybe consider leaving a thoughtful comment or helping with the maintenance on the linked code.

---

**As a workaround**, I've been enabling "Falloff Opacity" under "Cursor" in the brush settings. Running this line in a Python Console view will do it for all brushes: `[[setattr(b, 'use_cursor_overlay', True), setattr(b, 'cursor_overlay_alpha', 5)] for b in bpy.data.brushes.values()]`.

Comment: oh, Thank you very much for these infos, but unfortunately i dont have that much experience codding with python :\

Comment: @YonalJayasinghe As a workaround, I've been enabling "Falloff Opacity" under "Cursor" in the brush settings. Running this line in a Python Console view will do it for all brushes: `[[setattr(b, 'use_cursor_overlay', True), setattr(b, 'cursor_overlay_alpha', 5)] for b in bpy.data.brushes.values()]`.

Comment: @WillChen All I get when I enter that code is: [[None, None], [None, None]... repeated a 100 times give or take.

Comment: @EricHuelin Yes. `setattr()` returns `None` after doing its work. Check your sculpt brushes; they should all have the cursor overlay enabled after running that line.

Comment: @WillChen I was hoping that would bring back my Texture paint brush cursor. No such luck.